Font of equation labels in Beamer
I have the following Beamer program:
\documentclass[16pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}
\useinnertheme[shadow=false]{rounded}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\usecolortheme{whale}


%   %-------------%
%   |     Font    |
%   %-------------%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{FiraSans}
\usepackage{FiraMono}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\huge, shape=\scshape\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{size=\Large, shape=\scshape, parent=structure}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\Large, shape=\scshape}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\large, shape=\scshape}
\setbeamerfont{date}{size=\large, shape=\scshape}
\setbeamerfont{sectiontitle}{size=\huge, series=\scshape\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{subsectiontitle}{size=\Large, series=\scshape\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\Large, shape=\scshape}
\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\scriptsize}
\setbeamerfont{focusframe}{size=\huge, shape=\scshape}
\setbeamerfont{description item}{shape=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{caption name}{shape=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography item}{size=\small, shape=\scshape}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry author}{size=\small, shape=\scshape}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry title}{size=\small, series=\scshape\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry location}{size=\small, shape=\scshape\normalfont}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry note}{size=\small, shape=\scshape\normalfont}


\begin{document}


\section{First section}
\begin{frame}
\begin{equation}
aaa = \beta_{c} 1
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
\section{Third section}


\end{document}

Which has the following output:

I want to change the family font of just the equation labels to serif, leaving all the other stuff unchanged

Unrelated, but you don't need to load amsmath or xcolor, beamer loads them automatically

16pt isn't a valid class option. You will get a 11pt font instead.

You can redefine \maketag@@@#1 as shown in this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/584160/36296 :
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}
\useinnertheme[shadow=false]{rounded}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{(\ignorespaces\ref{#1}\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}
\def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox{\m@th\normalfont\rmfamily#1}}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}


\section{First section}
\begin{frame}
\begin{equation}
aaa = \beta_{c} 1 \label{key}
\end{equation}

\eqref{key} test
\end{frame}

\end{document}


If you don't mind the reference also being in serif, you could use mathtools:
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}
\useinnertheme[shadow=false]{rounded}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\newtagform{serif}{\rmfamily(}{)}
\usetagform{serif}

\begin{document}


\section{First section}
\begin{frame}
\begin{equation}
aaa = \beta_{c} 1 \label{key}
\end{equation}
test \eqref{key} test
\end{frame}
\end{document}


